# Error in file that is already deleted

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, netbeans

I am getting errors in tomcat's log window (using netbeans 7.2 with tomcat 7). I have deleted that file but log is still pointing to that file and line numbers.

```
An error occurred at line: 14 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.mycomp.domain.LoginModel resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: 6 in the jsp file: /WEB-INF/jsp/header.jsp
LoginModel cannot be resolved to a type
3: <div class="header" >
4:     <!--header start here -->
5:     <%
6:         LoginModel loginModel;
7:         loginModel = (LoginModel) request.getSession(false).getAttribute("loginModel");
8:     %>
9:     <div>
```

After deleting header.jsp, I have clean and build many times but still same error.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the project is not getting automatically deployed to the server. Have you checked your deployment settings?